# Using lein ring server, how to switch to another adapter than ring-jetty-adapter

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

Given a simple webapplication like

```
(ns webtest.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]))

(defroutes app-routes
           (GET "/" [] "Hello World")
           (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults)))
```

that can be started using `lein ring server`, how would one be able to adapt the project to switch out the jetty adapter for another ring adapter, for instance [undertow](https://github.com/luminus-framework/ring-undertow-adapter) or http-kit?

For reference, here's the excerpt of the lein `project.clj` in use:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
                 [ring "1.8.1" :exclusions [ring/ring-jetty-adapter]]
                 [luminus/ring-undertow-adapter "1.1.0"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.2"]
                 [compojure "1.6.1"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.12.5"]]
  :ring {:handler webtest.handler/app}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can use `:adapter` key.</strike>

Finally I tested and no, the tag `:adapter` allows to pass the options for ring.jetty.adapter only.
After analyse the source code, there is no possibility to switch the adapter.

Here an reponse from the plugin author to a similar query:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24307363/5773724